# I can't get ssh-server to start without prompting for my password [WSL2]

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, sshd

sorry if this question is stupid or something, I'm not very proficient in the Linux world. In fact, I've only come this long way because I want to use Valgrind in CLion on my Windows machine.

While trying to figure out how I can accomplish, I had to go over multiple steps, also involving setting up the ssh server in my WSL instance (Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS). For that I found [this](https://www.illuminiastudios.com/dev-diaries/ssh-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux/) very helpful walkthrough. However, I got stuck at

> run the command `sudo visudo`

> add the following line `%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/sshd` after `%sudo  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`

> You can test that you don’t need a sudo password when you start ssh by running `sudo service ssh --full-restart` (if ssh is already running) or `sudo service ssh start` (if ssh is not running)

Problem is that whatever I do, I cannot get `sudo service ssh --full-restart` to work without prompting me for a password. I did try quite a lot of other things by now but nothing changes anything. This is what I've tried so far:

- checking that the sudoers file actually contains that extra line after editing (it does)
- go through this [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/dentechy/de2be62b55cfd234681921d5a8b6be11)
- [I found out](https://gist.github.com/dentechy/de2be62b55cfd234681921d5a8b6be11#gistcomment-2581303) that the gist is outdated for Ubuntu versions 18.04 and higher. So I looked at the [updated gist](https://gist.github.com/harleyday/76a103a1a0ca97c6f33706e4a8cc3307) and replaced `/usr/sbin/sshd` with `/etc/init.d/ssh`
- I used `wsl -t Ubuntu` to stop the WSL instance and restarted it after editing to make sure it's not some kind of restart issue
- Following [this comment](https://gist.github.com/dentechy/de2be62b55cfd234681921d5a8b6be11#gistcomment-3068190) on the original gist, I checked the whitespace characters in my sudoers file and found out that everything used tabs, but my line had spaces. I replaced the spaces with a tab
- I saw two posts on this StackExchange and browsed the answers, found barely anything new/helpful. I tried two things: Putting the new line at the bottom of the file and checking that `sudo` is not aliased

After all this research / troubleshooting, I just don't know what else I could be missing here. If anyone has an idea how I could get this to work, I'd be very thankful.

System:

- Windows 10 Pro
- WSL 2
- Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: The command `service ssh --full-restart` is not the command that you specified in your sudeors file that you should be able to run without a password.

Comment: Hm, that actually makes sense but for some reason none of the sources I was referring to mentions this (for example, look at the quote from the first website: They literally tell you to test it by invoking `service ssh start`). Well if that's the wrong way, what's the right way? Thanks for the reply btw

Comment: @RaphaelTarita They are using `sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -D` in the batch script to start the service without password ("Follow the next steps which will create scripts that start the ssh server automatically").

Comment: @Freddy Thank you so much, your comment pointed me in the right direction! Running `sudo /usr/bin/sshd` apparently has some problems with UsePrivilegeSeparation, but I just switched to using `sudo /etc/init.d/ssh start` (as mentioned in the updated github gist and in the article, later on), but then I also had to set that path in the sudoers file. Running this command does indeed not prompt me for a password! Still weird that this one article told me to test with `service ssh start`..

Comment: In my experience, an ssh server within WSL is less reliable because it's hard to get WSL to always be running. OpenSSH for Windows works well for me; here are the instructions I wrote: [Installing OpenSSH on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58223575/10590519)

Comment: @bitinerant I am only using an ssh server in WSL to connect to it from the same machine and access the Valgrind executable

Comment: ssh to windows machine works fine, but then how to rsync for example, looks like you cannot even robocopy via ssh in windows, scp works but it's not enough. 
I am new to windows, and I am a little bit stuck with some things out there, so be able to log into good old ubuntu and have full filesystem access, helps a bit :-)